# Pixels to Inches

Tags: vb.net

I've searched for a while now, but can't seem to get the answer I'm looking for.
I have an image, when I do properties on that image it says:

Dimensions  1717x697
Width  1717 pixels
Height  697 pixels
Horizontal Resolution  96 dpi
Vertical Resolution  96 dpi
Bit depth  32

So everything I've found searching says to get inches you are supposed to divide the pixels by the dpi...

So when I divide 697 by 96 I get 7.26041...
The height of my document that was scanned was 3.5 inches tall...how is that possible?

What I'm trying to do is if I have a piece of paper that is scanned and that piece of paper is 3.5 by 8.5 (coupon) I want to be able to know the the inches of that document based on pixels or some other method.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Monitor DPI =/= Scanning DPI

Comment: http://tiporama.com/tools/pixels_inches.html

Comment: 1 "twip" = 1/20 of a point. 1 point ~ 1.333 pixels (this depends on screen resolution; most monitors today run 96 pixels per inch in their native resolution